# Google Recaptcha v2 and preventdefault

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, recaptcha

on my website I have an ajax form with google recaptcha. I am using event.preventdefault() to keep the page from reloading. Before I added the captcha everything was working fine. However, now whenever I try to submit the form I always get the error message that the captcha was not ticked even when it was.

If i remove the event.preventdefault() everything is working fine, even with the captcha, only that I get redirected to my submission.php.

Are google recaptcha v2 and event.preventdefault() generally incompatible?
And what can I do to have a captcha and keep the page from reloading?

EDIT

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#contactform").submit(function(event) {
    $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error"), $(".help-block").remove();
    event.preventDefault()
    var formData = {
        name: $("input[name=name]").val(),
        email: $("input[name=email]").val(),
        message: $("textarea[name=message]").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://example.com/form-submission.php",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        encode: true

    }).done(function(data) {
        if ( ! data.success) {

          if (data.errors.name) {
              $('#name-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
              $('#name-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.name + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
          }

          if (data.errors.email) {
              $('#email-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
              $('#email-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.email + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
          }

          if (data.errors.message) {
              $('#message-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
              $('#message-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.message + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
          }

          if (data.errors.captcha) {
              $('#captcha-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
              $('#captcha-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.captcha + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
            }

        } else {
            $("#contactheadline").append('<div class="submissionsuccess">' + data.message + "</div>");
            document.getElementById("contactform").style.display = "none";
          }

    });
});
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php


$errors         = array();      // array to hold validation errors
$data           = array();      // array to pass back data


function post_captcha($user_response) {
    $fields_string = '';
    $fields = array(
        'secret' => '_key_',
        'response' => $user_response
    );
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
    $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
   'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($result, true);
}

// Call the function post_captcha
$res = post_captcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

if (empty($_POST['name']))
    $errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';

if (empty($_POST['email']))
    $errors['email'] = 'Email is required.';

if (empty($_POST['message']))
    $errors['message'] = 'Message is required.';

if (!$res['success'])
    $errors['message'] = 'Please tick the Captcha.';


if (!empty($errors)) {
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['errors']  = $errors;

  } else {

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $email_from = 'form-submission@example.com';address
        $to = "info@example.com";
        $email_subject = "New Form submission";
        $email_body = "You have received a new message from $name ($visitor_email). \n $message \r\n".

        $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email";

        mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['message'] = "Thank you for contacting us! We have received your message and will get back to you shortly.";
    }


// return all data to an AJAX call
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The code would be helpful ... which data are you sending with the async call?

Comment: Of course, I have added the code to the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i expected, you are not sending the entire form but only 3 elements (name, email and message). That's why your recaptcha is invalid, try sending the entire form instead:

```
var form = document.getElementById("contactform");
// or with jQuery
//var form = $("#contactform")[0];

$.ajax({
    // the formData function is available in almost all new browsers.
    data: new FormData(form),
    // Rest of your configuration
});
```